# What preposition should I use for "head over heels"

Tags: prepositions

I am confused about the preposition I should use with

> "I was head over heels for her"

I was thinking of using "for". but is this correct?

Comment: *For* is fine, but the preposition is not dictated by the "head over heels" itself, but rather by the context. "Commenters are not head over heels *for* [this] look", but "he is head over heels *in* gambling debts" or "I fell head over heels *into* the kitchen" (all citations from COCA). More typically the phrase is not used with *be*, but with another verb which then dictates the choice. You *fall for* her, and so you *fall* head over heels *for* her, too. You *are in love with* her, and so you *are* head over heels *in love with* her.

Comment: (COCA has cites 251 in total, I think my favorite so far got to be "his corpse dropped head over heels onto Cholesterin's plump body".)

Answer (score 1):

*head over heels for* and *head over heels with* are both used, as well as *head over heels in love with ...*.

Comment: Evidence? Without it, why should anyone believe you. I don’t (except for the latter, which I could document. But this is an ELL question — why answer it?